# Returning variables PHP, MySQL and JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm developing an PHP-MySQL-JS platorm. I'm doing now the profile page and there the user can update his info. 
My code is:

**HTML**

```
<form> 
  //rest of the form.
  //The submit button.      
          <button id="profile_submit" style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 10px;" class="logout" type="submit"><b>Guardar cambios</b></button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#profile_submit').click(function(){
      var name1 = $('#name1').val();
      var name2 = $('#name2').val();
      var user = $('#user').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();

      if(name1 != '' && name2 != '' && user != '' && email != '' ){
       $.ajax({
          url: '../controller/updateuser.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {name1: name1, name2: name2, user: user, email: email},
          success: function(msg){
                    if (msg == '1'){
                    //Error
                        alert("Another user is using this email already");

                    } else {
                        //Se registro
                        alert("Updated");
                        setTimeout(function(){location.href= "workspace.php"} , 1000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
  }); 
});
```

**PHP - general**

```
public function update_user($name1, $name2, $user, $email){

            $res = $this->conexion->query("select USR_EMAIL from usr_usuario where USR_EMAIL = '".$email."' and USR_DELETE = '0' and USR_ID <> '".$_COOKIE['USR_ID']."' ");

                if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
                {
                    //Email used
                    echo '1';
                }else{
                    //Update user

                    $this->conexion->query("UPDATE usr_usuario SET USR_USERNAME = '".$user."', USR_NAME = '".$name1."', USR_NAME2 = '".$name2."', USR_EMAIL = '".$email."' WHERE USR_ID = '".$_COOKIE['USR_ID']."' ");


                }

}
```

**PHP - update.php**

```
 <?php 
           require("../modelo/conexion.php");

    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $object = new conexion(); 
    $object -> actualizar_usuario($name1, $name2, $user, $email);
    $object -> cerrar();


   ?>
```

Well, when the user clicks on the button with id="profile_submit", the JS read the info in the inputs and sends it to update.php and it calls the update_user in general php file.

When the user insert an email used already it works perfectly, but, when all is okay, the sql UPDATE works but the rest of the code(PHP and JS) don't sends nothing to the user.
I don't know why this happens...

Help please.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It seems you are not returning anything from your php script (on fail you echo 1 on success nothing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will study this instruction. But why the "else" on the general PHP don't work? :(